# How to show pop up div from server side on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on Payment page and i want to show a popup for showing message your payment is processing. so for now i am using CustomValidator and Submit Button. and i want to show this popup when Args is valid. my code is.

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="" OnServerValidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate"
                                            EnableClientScript="true" ValidationGroup="Authorize"></asp:CustomValidator>

<asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" runat="server" Text="Pay now" CausesValidation="true" CssClass="blue paynow" style="width:200px;"
                                                ValidationGroup="Authorize" OnClick="SubmitButton_Click" OnClientClick="validate(ContentPlaceHolder1_chk_agree);" />
```

Comment: Are you using external control libraries like Devexpress or Telerik, or you using jQueryUi ?

Answer (score 1):

To show a message box after validation, you can do the following:
Add the following javascript to your `<head>`

```
<script language="javascript">
    function SubmitButton_ClientClick()
    {
       bool isValid = Page_ClientValidate("Authorize"); //triggers validation
       if (isValid)
       {
           alert('Your payment is processing');
       }

       return isValid;
    }
</script>
```

Then, change your button like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" runat="server" Text="Pay now" CausesValidation="true" 
            CssClass="blue paynow" style="width:200px;"
            ValidationGroup="Authorize" OnClick="SubmitButton_Click"  
            OnClientClick="return SubmitButton_ClientClick();" />
```

**An even better approach is to use a popup div** - here is a very basic example:

Add this somewhere in your `<body>`

```
<div id="popup_box" style="height:300;width:300;position:absolute;top:150;left:350;border:3px solid red;background:#d8d8d8;display:none;">
    <h1>Payment is processing</h1>
    <button id="popupBoxClose" onclick="document.getElementById("popup_box").style.display = 'none';">Close</button>
</div>
```

And modify the `SubmitButton_ClientClick` like this:

```
function SubmitButton_ClientClick()
{
   bool isValid = Page_ClientValidate("Authorize"); //triggers validation
   if (isValid)
   {
      document.getElementById("popup_box").style.display = '';
   }

   return isValid;
}
```

Comment: alert..user have to close this manually after payment done !!

Comment: I mean will this alert box close automatically when the payment process is completed ?

Comment: No, but that was not what OP asked, he asked for a popup

Comment: popup div, but that's me being pedantic ;o)

Comment: Thanks Blachshma, this is working for me and just answer me if payment is unsuccessful like user entered invalid Card details or something like this. then the popup should hide. and i am getting error in Custom Validator.

Comment: Are you referring to AFTER the postback?

Answer (score 1):

One better approach is to go with "updateProgress".

Place your submit button inside a updatePanel and place a loading gif image inside updateProgress which **will show below loading image** when payment progress is going on and will close automatically when payment is complete.

[image] **Loading ....**

```
<asp:UpdateProgress id="updateProgress" runat="server">
     <ProgressTemplate>
            <asp:Image ID="imgUpdateProgress" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/loadingNew.gif" AlternateText="Loading ..." ToolTip="Loading ..."/>
     </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Comment: If i leave all the fields and click on submit then Required Field Validator is showing but as well as this image is also showing but i want to do if all the fields is filled and click on submit then this image should show.

Comment: here is only my button inside update panel, its works for me but the image is showing every time click on button if the text fields are black.